# How to Cause Bars to Overlap in VCL TeeChart

Tags: teechart

I have two series in a horizontal TeeDBChart.  I would like to draw one series behind the other.  The help says that "...you can choose if they will be drawn side-by-side, back-to-front or Stacked."  Side-by-side and stacked choices are reasonably obvious, but how do I display them back-to-front?

I used to have this working perfectly, but now it doesn't.  Not sure exactly when it broke.

Here's a rundown of the Multiple Bar settings:
None = all bars from both series in a single spot on the axis - complete overlap
Side = all bars from a series in a single spot on the axis - overlap within series
Side All = all bars from both series spread across the axis evenly - no overlap

What I really want is bars to be matched and overlapped based on axis values.  That is, bars for the same axis value will overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting series' [MultiBar property](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/lib/html/TCustomBarSeries.MultiBar.html) to [mbNone](http://www.teechart.net/docs/teechart/vclfmx/lib/html/TMultiBar.html), for example:

```
uses VCLTee.Series;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var Series1, Series2: THorizBarSeries;
begin
  Series1 := THorizBarSeries.Create(Self);
  Series1.FillSampleValues();
  Series1.MultiBar := mbNone;

  Series2 := THorizBarSeries.Create(Self);
  Series2.FillSampleValues();
  Series2.MultiBar := mbNone;

  Chart1.AddSeries(Series1);
  Chart1.AddSeries(Series2);
end;
```

Code above produces this chart:

[image]

Is this what you are looking for? Otherwise, can you please post a code snippet reproducing your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, that puts all bars from both series in a single stack.  Thanks for the attempt, though.